# Match a pattern and then go to the next condition and print the details

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This is my demo file: Demo.txt

```
CP                                  Used
-----------------------------------  --------------
gyhjjjjjjjjjjjjj
gdhdhsdjjsdjsd
-----------------------------------  --------------
                        list:        21305 

DP                                     Used
-----------------------------------  --------------
asghjskkkkkkkkkkfe jfdkjcdf
ashdjdjksd
-----------------------------------  --------------
                         list:       203899
```

Here I want to match DP and then match list and print the details.

Expected output is:

```
21305,"CP"
203899,"DP"
```

Comment: Not clear, please wrap your sample correctly into code tags again. also show your effort which you have put to solve this problem too in your post.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We really need a *"Givez mez the codez"* Stack Exchange.

Comment: @jww, I don't want to debate here but if a person is new to coding or new to SO we may give him/her chance to learn(at least they could have few posts) and then we could push them more to learn here(which I agree too). Simply giving down votes discourages people(specially like me who are not experts but trying to learn by helping people).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse a simple table with awk:

```
awk '$2=="Used"{x=$1}; $1=="list:"{print $2",\""x"\""}' Demo.txt
```

- If column 2 contains `Used` then save content of column 1 to variable `x`.
- If column 1 contains `list:` then print column 2 and content of variable `x`.

Output:

```
21305,"CP"
203899,"DP"
```

Answer (score 0):

Same approach like Cyrus sir's with a little difference of using variables and using `$NF` for string `list` value as follows.

```
awk -v s1="\"" -v s2="," '/Used/{val=$1;next} /list:/{print $NF s2 s1 val s1;val=""}'  Input_file
```